# how to upload a solution to vsts/ azure devops from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops

how can you create a solution in visual studio and when you save it to create a rep in VSTS and upload it?

I want to create an azure resource group folder then when i save it to automatically creates a repo in my vsts account and also upload the solution files

Comment: Do you work with Git or TFVC?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with a web application, see the [Publish a Web app to Azure App Service using Visual Studio Quick Start Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-azure?view=vs-2017#prerequisites). It should contain all necessary steps on how to publish your web app with configuration that suits your needs.

If my memory serves me right, so long as your Visual Studio instance is connected to an account with access to contribute to an Azure DevOps instance, you should be able to create new Git repositories when creating your solution.

From there, you should publish your local repository to your DevOps instance (I'd recommend reading the [Git branching guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-branching-guidance?view=vsts#keep-your-branch-strategy-simple)) once your particular feature is complete.

Comment: no not working with a web app, creating infrastructure vms, vnets etc